# add element to upload image

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I try to add a file bottom to add image in joomla 3.0 backend

For this I use append() function of Jquery

```
<div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('imagenes'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls1"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('imagenes'); ?>
                <input type="button" id="boton_append_1" value="Add Imagen" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my jquery function is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery.noConflict();
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery('#boton_append_1').click(function() {
                        jQuery('.controls1').append(

                        );
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

But I don´t know how to put the element to add

any idea

Comment: *`to add a file bottom`* ... you mean: **"to add a File Button"** ?

Comment: yes @roXOn something like this php echo $this->form->getInput('imagenes');  that generate a input type="file" bottom

Comment: Why don't you try jQuery('.controls1').append('<input type="file" />);

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertBefore()`.

**Official Document** : http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        jQuery('#boton_append_1').click(function()
        {
            jQuery('<input type="file" />').insertBefore(jQuery(this));
        });
    });
</script>
```